# Kotlin collection functions equivalent in swift

Tags: swift, kotlin, stream

So im coming from a rich kotlin background and currently diving into iOS development using swift. And I'm really missing my collection functions that Kotlin provides us natively,

like sublist, first,

I think it's called the stream api in java.

Is there an swift equivalent for this in the form of a Pod?

Comment: Refer this :: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: the collection is natively build in the language no need for pods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

```
var arr = [1,2,3]
let res = arr[0...1] // [1,2] sublist in kotlin
let fir = arr.first // optional(1) first in kotlin
```